# deinit in Swift behavior

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, deinit

I wrote the following code in a `Swift playground` :

```
class View : UIView {
    let name = "myView"
    deinit {
        print("deinit View")
    }
}

class Controller: NSObject {
    var view: View

    init(view : View) {
        self.view = view
        super.init()
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit Controller")
    }
}

var c : Controller? = Controller(view: View())
c = nil
```

the console shows :

```
deinit Controller
```

my question is shouldn't be like below ?

```
deinit Controller
deinit View
```

Comment: I tried it and it behaves like this only in playgorund and only if `View` is subclass of `UIView`. UIKit is just not meant to be used in playground

Comment: and btw it should be `deinit Controller` and then `deinit View` but it doesn't actually matter

Comment: @lukasbalaz7 I have updated the question. Also in Xcode with a real project it behaves the same

Comment: @Bobj-C I does relate to UIView, however. Try your example without subclassing `View` to `UIView`: you then get the expected output.

Comment: @lukasbalaz7 - "UIKit is just not meant to be used in playground" ... I'm not sure why you say that. We do it all the time. But, to your point, you don't generally use view controllers and views in playgrounds, though WWDC 2015 [Authoring Rich Playgrounds](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-405/) demonstrates how you do precisely that.

Comment: I can see the expected result in my iOS project. I think your app just terminates before everything is deallocated (the autorelease pool drained)

Comment: @Rob yes it is the actual code "copy paste"

Comment: The core "problem" (seen by some of us, not others?) is the `View` class. If I try "var d : View? = View` followed by `d = nil`, nothing is printed for me. Using Swift 2.1.1 and Xcode 7.2.

Comment: @Rob have u tried it in Xcode project ?

Comment: This looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082011/weak-references-in-swift-playground-dont-work-as-expected