# What is it difference of weak reference in some cases in Swift?

Tags: swift

For example, has :

```
class Person {
   let name: String
   init(name: String) {
     self.name = name
     print("\(name) is being initialized")
   }
   deinit {
     print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
  }
}
```

// Case 1:

```
var reference1: Person? = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
weak var reference2: Person?
weak var reference3: Person?
reference2 = reference1
reference3 = reference1
reference1 = nil
print(reference1 ?? "nil") // nil
print(reference2 ?? "nil") // Person
print(reference3 ?? "nil") // Person

//Case 2:
var reference1: Person? = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
weak var reference2: Person? = reference1
weak var reference3: Person? = reference1
reference1 = nil
print(reference1 ?? "nil") // nil
print(reference2 ?? "nil") // nil
print(reference3 ?? "nil") // nil
```

I would to like to ask why the weak reference is different in cases? Thanks for help.

Comment: Playground? Your first example shows 3 `nil` to me.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Playground. I still don't understand it. Please tell me details.

Comment: Playground can sometimes retain an object to display it. Playgrounds were created to teach to language, they don't have to be reliable for memory management tests. Try it in a normal application.

Comment: See [Weak references in Swift playground don't work as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082011/weak-references-in-swift-playground-dont-work-as-expected)