# Strong Reference not turning into weak when deinitialize

Tags: swift, swift4

I am learning about weak references from a YouTube Video and the person said that I need to put a weak reference on the author in the courses class and that will solve my problem.

Although on Playgrounds the deinitalize method still does not appear.

What else am I doing wrong? Is the strong relationship still in place by the `author.courses.append(self)`?

Please let me know as I am trying to learn the best practices of handling these type of situations and prevent memory leaks.

```
public class Author {

    public var name: String
    public var courses = [Course]()

    public init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print("Author \(name)")
    }

    deinit {
        print("Author \(name) deinitialized")
    }

}


public class Course {

    public var title: String
    public weak var author: Author?
    public init(title: String, author: Author) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        author.courses.append(self)
        print("Course \(title)")
    }

    deinit {
        print("Course \(title) deinitialized")
    }

}

var author: Author? = Author(name: "John Doe")
var course: Course? = Course(title: "Best Swift Course Ever", author: author!)

author = nil
course = nil
```

Comment: Please don't forget to respond to the answers of your earlier questions. Please go back through all of your existing questions, and where appropriate, respond to comments and/or accept answers that solved your issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weak references in Swift playground don't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082011/weak-references-in-swift-playground-dont-work-as-expected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playgrounds can hold strong references to your data for the purpose of previews. To get a true depiction of the deinitialization of a piece of code, test it outside of a playground.

Furthermore, when a weak reference exists to an object, the deinitializer isn't actually called immediately when the last weak reference is released. Instead, the object is deinitialized the next time the weak reference is attempted to be accessed. See [this blog post](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-09-22-swift-4-weak-references.html) for more details.

Comment: If I understand that blog post correctly (but I did not look into the implementation), deinit is called immediately then the last (strong) reference is gone, only the side table is kept until the last weak reference is gone.

Comment: @MartinR Lol! I read an older version ([this one](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-12-11-swift-weak-references.html), I think), in which what I said was accurate (at the time). I thought that's what I was linking to, but apparently there's this new version, and i didn't notice the difference.

Comment: Even then: *“When a Swift object's strong reference count reaches zero while the weak count is still greater than zero, the object **is deinitialized** but not deallocated”*